# Как разрешить ввод пропса при условии что другой пропс был заполнен?

Tags: typescript

подскажите пожалуйста, как описать тип, чтобы при отстутсвии определенного ключа, запрещать ввод другого?)

```
interface Base {
  top?: number;
  left?: number;
  behavior?: "auto" | "smooth"
}

interface OffsetTopProps {
  offsetTop?: number;
}

interface OffsetLeftProps {
  offsetLeft?: number;
}

// в случае если top был заполнен, то offsetTop можно вводить offsetTop?: number; аналогично с left
```

пробовал через union сделать, но не получилось

```
type test = Base | OffsetTopProps | OffsetLeftProps
```

Comment: перенеси top и left в соответствующие интерфейсы обязытальными

Answer (score 0):

Вот такое решение в итоге:

```
type TopOptions =
  | { top: number; offsetTop?: number; isConsiderHeader?: boolean }
  | { top?: never; offsetTop?: never; isConsiderHeader?: never };

type LeftOptions = { left: number; offsetLeft?: number } | { left?: never; offsetLeft?: never };

type Options = ScrollToOptions & TopOptions & LeftOptions;
```

конечно получаем немного кривые ошибки от ts, но в остальном, вроде все работает

Answer (score -1):

Cамое простое — это использовать `миксины` и `объединения` одновременно, миксинами задаем 4 возможных варианта:

- `left` и `top` не заданы
- только `left` задан
- только `top` задан
- `left` и `top` заданы

а `union` позволит `TS` выбирать между ними. Все работает как нужно в качестве ошибок, но есть и ложка дегтя в этом решении — ошибки отображаются не совсем точно, например:

```
const t3: test = {
  offsetTop: 1
}
```

> Type '{ offsetTop: number; }' is not assignable to type 'test'.
> Type '{ offsetTop: number; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Base4': top, left

```
const t4: test = {
  offsetLeft: 1
}
```

> Type '{ offsetLeft: number; }' is not assignable to type 'test'.
> Type '{ offsetLeft: number; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Base4': top, left

(Другие варианты проходят без ошибок можно посмотреть [тут](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=43&pln=1&pc=1#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-VbA8GHTsIyao5pmTpLdl4-bQwBWZOyM3xYzCIA))

Если такая точность ошибки не смущает, решение можно считать рабочим.

**Весь код**:

```
type Top = {
  top: number;
  offsetTop?: number;
}

type Left = {
  left: number;
  offsetLeft?: number;
}

type Behavior =  {
  behavior?: "auto" | "smooth"
} 

interface Base1 extends Behavior {}
interface Base2 extends Top, Behavior {}
interface Base3 extends Left, Behavior {}
interface Base4 extends Top, Left, Behavior {}

type test  = Base1 | Base2 | Base3 | Base4
```